# How to store types like IPEndPoint with Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, store

I've been looking around for a long time to find out how to store CLR-Types like IPEndPoint in a database with Entity Framework 6. In my special case I have a child class of IPEndPoint adding some properties (ExtendedIPEndPoint).

Normally it should be a common use case but I really couldn't find any explanation how to do it. In theory it's quiet simple, for storing just take the IPAddress property and map it to a String and second take the Port property and map it to an integer. To load the ExtendedIPEndPoint just create a new object using the constructor and additional methods like IPAddress.Parse, to parse the IPAddress out of the stored string.

I've heard about complex types, stored procedures and proxies but I really dont know how to use them and where's a good explanation if these are correct words to search for.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, you only need to store the data needed to build the type you want to represent.

Since `IPEndPoint` has a [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k17zbw22%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) with a `IPAddress` and an `int`, you need to be able to store those values. So since an `IPAddres` is also not a SQL type, we'll need data for a [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4k07yby(v=vs.110).aspx) for that too:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public byte[] IPAddressData { get; set; }
    public int Port { get; set; }

    private IPAddress _IPAddress;
    [NotMapped]
    public IPAddress IPAddress
    {
        get
        {
            if(_IPAddress == null) 
                _IPAddress = new IPAddress(IPAddressData);
            return _IPAddress;
        }
    }

    private IPEndPoint _IPEndPoint 
    [NotMapped]
    public IPEndPoint IPEndPoint 
    {
        get
        {
            if(_IPEndPoint == null) 
                _IPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress, Port);
            return _IPEndPoint;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use that constructor... You are limiting it to IPv4 (*address is less than 0 or greater than 0x00000000FFFFFFFF*).

Comment: noted. I just took the first constructor i saw, I'll look into another one